# No clean the form if I have an error Django

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a form that is using .error validations, the problem is that if I get and error, it erase all the data, writen before and in some parts I'm using ajax calls and it clean all that data too, what can I do, so that I get the error, but still have me fields filled.

views.py

```
@permission_required(
'expmedico.can_access_expmedico', login_url='/acceso-denegado')
def registro_expediente(request):
"""
Funcion para dar de alta nuevos expedientes medicos.
"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario = ExpedienteInicialform(request.POST)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        print formulario
        formulario.save()
        id_miembro = request.POST.get('credencial_consultainicial')
        medico = request.POST.get('medico_atencion')
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        no_expediente = ExpedienteConsultaInicial.objects.filter(
            credencial_consultainicial=id_miembro, fecha_atencion_18=now, medico_atencion=medico).latest('id')
        return render_to_response('altaexitosaexpedienteinicial.html', {'no_expediente': no_expediente}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        print formulario.errors
        return render_to_response('prueba.html', {'formulario': formulario},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        messages.success(request, 'Se presento un error al dar de alta')
else:
    formulario = ExpedienteInicialform()
    user_medico = request.user
    medico = Medico.objects.filter(username=user_medico)
    if medico.exists():
        id_medico = medico[0].pk
        nombre_medico = medico[0].nombre
        apellido_medico = medico[0].ap_paterno
    else:
        id_medico = 67
        nombre_medico = "Invitado"
        apellido_medico = "Invitado"

return render_to_response(
    'prueba.html', {'formulario': formulario,'id_medico':id_medico,'nombre_medico':nombre_medico,'apellido_medico':apellido_medico},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: It would probably be easier for others to follow your code if you used English variables and strings when posting.

Comment: People do help me even if my code is in spanish, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you include ```prueba.html```? Particularly any where you use ```formulario```.